# MultiSpeak API: How to Put Database Values in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

I am working on MultiSpeak API--I am not familiar with that. A function is as follows:

```
 public meter[] GetMeterByAccountNumber(string accountNumber) {
 meter myMeter = new meter();//IS this declaration right?
//some query work and next is sql data reader
 int i = 0;
 while (rdr.Read())
    {
      myMeter[i].deviceClass = rdr["deviceClass"].ToString();//error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to type 'meter'
      i++;
    }
  return myMeter[]; //generates ERROR: Value expected.
}
```

I don't know what this return type of '`GetMeterByAccountNumber`' is but it does expect a return of `meter[]` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetMeterByAccountNumber` is not the return type, it's the function name.

You could do somthing like this, however I would call it **GetMetersByAccountNumber** as it returns an array/IEnumerable

Also i'm not sure what deviceClass has to do with account number..

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic
```

---

```
 public IEnumerable<meter> GetMetersByAccountNumber(string accountNumber) {
    var items = new List<meter>();
    //some query work and next is sql data reader

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
      var deviceClass = rdr["deviceClass"].ToString();
      var meter = new meter();
      //Im guessing meter has some properties to set ?
      meter.deviceClass = deviceClass;
      items.Add(meter);
    }
    return items.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 'deviceClass' and a bunch of other fields are populated in current code but they only populate once and the return is fine from the function--but the function is supposed to return an array object--so there should be more than one 'meter' values not just one. Anyway, I am going to give your code a try. Thanks!

Comment: return items.AsReadOnly(); // error items does not exist in current context. Thx

Comment: Bigger problem when launching: Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[meter, MultiSpeakWebService, Version=1.0.2119.28772, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

Comment: If I declare the function as   public meter[] GetMetersByAccountNumber(string accountNumber) then the launch error goes away and indeed the items array now has multiple values. Still the return statement fails, as commented above. Getting closer though. Thanks!

Comment: The function expects to return meter[] type and hence fails in the Answer given. What I need is to somehow convert the items List to the meter type?

Comment: meter[] myArray = items.ToArray(); So getting closer. Still, the return says doesnt exist in current context; should be easy to fix.

Comment: I think got it. Will be posting a modified version of your Answer. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me, based on @Richard Friend's Answer. Thanks Richard!

```
public meter[] GetMetersByAccountNumber(string accountNumber)
{
     meter[] final_return;
      var items = new List<meter>();  
       while (rdr.Read())
        { 
            var meter = new meter();                
            meter.deviceClass = rdr["deviceClass"].ToString();
            items.Add(meter);
        }
        final_return = items.ToArray();
        return final_return;
}
```